# Why $\omega=vR$ can not be applied in this question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image]

[image]

I understand that $\omega_1=10rad/sec$ but after that I wanted to apply $v+R\omega_2$. But that gives the wrong result. Why is $v=R\omega_2$ wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's $v = R\omega$, not $\omega = Rv$.

Comment: Sorry. I am having a brain fart rn. But even after using $v=R\omega$ I won't get the right result because it's asking for the velocity along the rod. But $v=R\omega$ would give velocity perpendicular to the rod, right?

Comment: @Satya Correct, $R\omega$ is the tangential speed (perpendicular to the rod), it doesn't include the radial speed. The solution you show appears to use conservation of angular momentum to deduce the former and conservation of energy for the latter.